# How to tell if a customization is running in an Acumatica portal site vs standard Acumatica ERP site?

Tags: acumatica

Is there some call I can make in the Acumatica framework (other than looking for "SP" files) that indicates a site is a "Portal" site vs the standard Acumatica ERP instance site?

I need to turn off/on some logic if an instance is running as a portal site vs not running a portal site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the following static Boolean property:

```
PXSiteMap.IsPortal
```

Comment: Tested and confirmed this gives me what I need. Thanks for the quick and perfect answer.